# encoding issues with gbk pages , domxpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, extract

I'm trying to Curl the link below which is in GBK. I want to extract the title of the product and image. but when i echo the document to test if it's working , i dont get the chinese character. I need to extract using domxpath and display the characters on my website, same characters , not weird characters. How does this actually work?

```
$ch = curl_init("http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a2106.m874.1000384.41.aG3Kbi&id=20811635147&_u=o1ffj7oi9ad3&scm=1029.newlist-0.1.16&ppath=&sku=");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$searchPage = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'utf-8', "auto");
$doc->loadHTML($searchPage);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if mbstring.language in php.ini is set to GBK, or explicitly use

```
$searchPage = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'utf-8', "gb18030");
```

Comment: $searchPage = mb_convert_encoding($content,"HTML-ENTITIES","GBK"); is the solution

Comment: I manage to echo it correctly but when i do a $elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3"); and echo the title, it gives me å¤å­£è•¾ä¸å¼€è¡«é€æ˜Žè–„çº±å¤–å¥— é•‚ç©ºç»£èŠ±ä¸Šè¡£ ä¸­è¢–ç½‘çº±æ—¶å°šå¥³ä¸Šè¡£è–„æ¬¾

Comment: @CodeGuru helpful question and answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. and the solution work for me:

```
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  $str = mb_convert_encoding($str,'utf-8', "gb18030");
  $str = str_replace('<head>', '<head><meta HTTP-EQUIV=Content-Type content="text/html;charset=utf-8">', $str);
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  @$dom->loadHTML($str);
```

DOMDocument read your encoding declare in html, put it immediate after head